# UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationToken returning tokens unsuitable for URL transmission

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have a ASP.NET MVC 5 website, and I'm implementing an email confirmation process based on the template from Microsoft.

While I'm composing the email body text, first I construct the URL a user will use to "click to verify your address".

To generate the security token I call:

```
UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id)
```

This produces a code such as:

```
pporPNj6KzdZ3BYG8vQsKJu3dPJMwGgh+ZEGhCNnf9X6F0AS0f6qCowOQwQNfpYkl14bgEsmyPTKya5H6N4n2na2n5PgO+wpoihXxQTA7G8pK/lUYskX3jy2iA/ZM8m4Vm0prTyUuhMgfDlV+wkbR336FBRIAbKJDwOWvHHbJBDQ21gW93hyzca0li66aI1H
```

Obviously, this wouldn't be valid in a URL, but even URL encoding won't solve IIS's hate of such a URL.

```
HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.
```

In my UserManager implementation, I'm using the tutorial boilerplate code for a TokenProvider.

```
 var dataProtectionProvider = options.DataProtectionProvider;
        if (dataProtectionProvider != null)
        {
            manager.UserTokenProvider = new DataProtectorTokenProvider<SiteUser>(dataProtectionProvider.Create("ASP.NET Identity"));
        }
```

How can I make these generated tokens a bit more URL friendly?  What did potentially change that would prevent the ASP.NET's tutorial code not work?

Comment: Did you actually apply UrlEncoding?

Comment: Yes, using HttpUtility.UrlEncode(), and also by using a external tool, and passing the hard coded value in.

Comment: That's very strange. I've always used `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()` for tokens and never had such problem.

Comment: @trailmax, I found the solution. It's on the IIS side of interpreting the resulting string, rather than the generation side. I guess I can't use the URL format I was going for.

Comment: Ah, yes, the classical! I've tried exactly the same once - failed and had to go back)

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that this token will get mangled by the built in class "UrlHelper" in a MVC controller, or Url in a WebAPI controller IF the target route lists these variables as part of the path, rather than the GET vars of the URL.

Eg: this call, creates a relative URL for the site route called "ConfirmEmail" and fills in the blanks

```
Url.Route("ConfirmEmail", new { userId = user.Id, code = code });
```

Before my route was:

```
[Route("register-email/{code}/{userId}", Name = "ConfirmEmail")]
```

Changing this to:

```
    [Route("register-email", Name = "ConfirmEmail")]
```

Generates valid URLS that IIS can chew through. When these are not specified, they get appended after a ? mark as normal GET vars.  No idea why IIS is picky like that, but there's the solution.

Comment: If anyone wants to write up something a bit nicer, I'll happily award you the points for this solution. I wish I knew why this works the way it does.